# Предпросмотр картинок в Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

Как сделать такой предпросмотр картинок в IDE Webstorm ? 
При наведении на url появляется миниатюра
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+I` (**View | Quick definition**) на имени файла в URL должно помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]